# Customize separator page with client computer name

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer

I have a shared printer in a private network and I want to customize a separator page so that whenever one of my clients sends a page to my printer a separator page prints with his computer name in order to specify which computer sent this page.

I tried to configure the separator page from my server system but it just printed the server computer name.

I tried to set the separator page in each client computer but nothing happened and failed again.

So how can I customize the separator page in order to specify the owner of printed page?

My sever OS is windows 7 SP1 and my printer model is HP laser jet 1320

Comment: What operating system? What print maker/model?

Comment: @DavidPostill My OS is windows 7 SP1 and my printer model is HP leaser jet 1320

Answer (score 4):

#### How can I customize the separator page in order to specify the owner of printed page?

You can include `@N` (Prints the user name of the person that submitted the job) in a custom seperator file page.

---

#### How to create custom separator page files

> To create a custom separator page file, use a text editor such as
>   Notepad. On the very first line, type one single character, and then
>   press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The character on this line defines the
>   character used as an escape character. For example, the following list
>   assumes that this character is the at sign <kbd>@</kbd>.
>
> 1. Enter the escape codes for the functions you want, and then save the file with an `.sep` extension in the `%Windir%\System32`
>      subfolder.
> 2. In Print Manager, select the printer that you want to use the separator page file with, and then click "Choose Properties" on the
>      Printer menu.
> 3. Click "Details", specify the name of the desired separator page file in the "Separator File" box, and then click "OK".
>
> Note Put the custom separator page file in one of the following
>   locations:
>
> - In the `%Windir%\System32` folder.
> - In a folder whose path contains a `SepFiles` folder. For example:
>     `Drive:\Folder\SepFiles\Subfolder`
>
> The `@Fpathname` file will print only if the @Fpathname file is in one
>   of the following locations:
>
> - In the `%WINDIR%\System32` folder.
> - In a `SepFiles` folder that is under the `%WINDIR%\system32` folder, or in any subfolder of that `SepFiles` folder. For example:
>
>   ```
>   %WINDIR%\System32\SepFiles
>   ```
>
>   or
>
>   ```
>   %WINDIR%\System32\SepFiles\Subfolder1\Subfolder2
>   ```
> - In the same `SepFiles` folder as the custom separator page file, or in any subfolder of that `SepFiles` folder.
>
>   For example, the custom separator page file may be in the following folder:
>
>   ```
>   Drive:\Folder\SepFiles
>   ```
>
>   In this case, the `@Fpathname` file can be in the following folder:
>
>   ```
>   Drive:\Folder\SepFiles\Subfolder1\Subfolder2
>   ```
>
> The following list describes the escape codes that can be used in a
>   separator page file and their functions:
>
> - @N: Prints the user name of the person that submitted the job.
> - @I: Prints the job number.
> - @D: Prints the date the job was printed. The representation of the date is the same as the Date Format in the International section
>     in Control Panel.
> - @T: Prints the time the job was printed. The representation of the time is the same as the Time Format in the International section
>     in Control Panel.
> - @Lxxxx: Prints all the characters (xxxx) following it until another escape code is encountered.
> - @Fpathname: Prints the contents of the file specified by path, starting on an empty line. The contents of this file are copied
>     directly to the printer without any processing.
> - @Hnn: Sets a printer-specific control sequence, where nn is a hexadecimal ASCII code sent directly to the printer. To determine the
>     specific numbers, see your printer manual.
> - @Wnn: Sets the width of the separator page. The default width is 80; the maximum width is 256. Any printable characters beyond this
>     width are truncated.
> - @U: Turns off block character printing.
> - @B@S: Prints text in single-width block characters until @U is encountered.
> - @E: Ejects a page from the printer. Use this code to start a new separator page or to end the separator page file. If you get an extra
>     blank separator page when you print, remove this code from your
>     separator page file.
> - @n: Skips n number of lines (from 0 through 9). Skipping 0 lines moves printing to the next line.
> - @B@M: Prints text in double-width block characters until @U is encountered.

Source https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/102712

Answer (score 0):

David's answer tells you how to include the username in the separator file. Unfortunately there is no separator page parameter to display the computer name. However, as you can include the contents of a file, it can still be done, as follows.

In the startup script of the PC, have the following command:

echo %COMPUTERNAME% > %WINDIR%\System32\NAMEFILE.TXT

In this, change the path to suit the situation. Now, in the separator page, include the line

@F%WINDIR%\System32\NAMEFILE.TXT

I suggest you modify the file PCL.SEP, which comes with Windows (make a copy first), as that will give you a good starting point, and all you have to do is to insert an extra command. That will then print the name of the PC. You can use the other separator file parameters to specify the size, position, etc.